Shift+Space Not Working Without Sticky Keys Enabled in Excel
I'm encountering an issue with the Shift+Space shortcut in Microsoft Excel. Normally, this shortcut selects the entire row in the worksheet, but it only works when Sticky Keys is enabled on my Windows system. If Sticky Keys is off, pressing Shift+Space instead navigates into the cell for editing, which is not the desired behavior
I've tried checking the keyboard settings and ensuring there are no conflicting software that might be affecting the shortcut's functionality. I expected the shortcut to select the row regardless of the Sticky Keys setting.

Probably you have hotkey enabled for Power Toys see whether you have this particular application or not.

@MayukhBhattacharya PowerToys is not installed

You question best suits for SuperUser found something there may be help . Read
